# Retrieve all table names, column names and column values from specifc database

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to select all table names, column names, column values and display them with a single line group by table name. Here is the query.

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(a.table_name,'-',GROUP_CONCAT(a.column_name,':' 
                                         ORDER BY ordinal_position ASC)) 
    as table_data
FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = 'db_xxx'
) a
GROUP BY table_name
```

The above query works just fine to retrieve table names and column names but when I trying to get its column data with

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(a.table_name,'-',GROUP_CONCAT(a.column_name,':',
                            (SELECT a.column_name FROM a.table_name) 
                            ORDER BY ordinal_position ASC)) 
    as table_data
FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = 'db_xxx'
) a
GROUP BY table_name
```

It could not identify a.table_name in **(SELECT a.column_name FROM a.table_name)**. How should I fix this?

Comment: why do you need that part `(SELECT a.column_name FROM a.table_name)` at all. looks unnecessary

Comment: to get the respective column data?

Comment: So you want to build a subquery from a string containing the table name? You'll need to use prepared statements for that.

Answer (score 1):

To get table_name and column names you could use:

```
SELECT
 CONCAT(`table_name`, '-',
    GROUP_CONCAT(`column_name` ORDER BY ordinal_position SEPARATOR ':')) AS result
FROM information_schema.columns
-- WHERE `table_name` = ?
GROUP BY `table_name`;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7e201/1/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔══════════════╗
║    result    ║
╠══════════════╣
║ tab0-id:col  ║
║ tab1-id:col2 ║
║ tab2-id:col3 ║
╚══════════════╝
```

---

To get sample record for each column you need to use dynamic-sql:

```
SET @sql = '';

SELECT @sql := CONCAT(@sql, 
                      '(SELECT ''', `table_name`, ''' AS tab_name, ''', 
                                 `column_name`, ''' AS column_name, ',
                                 `ordinal_position`, ' AS ordinal_pos, ',
                                 `column_name`, ' AS sample '
                       'FROM ', `table_name` ,         
                       ' LIMIT 1) UNION ALL ')
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE `table_name` LIKE 'tab_';

SET @sql := SUBSTRING(@sql, 1, LENGTH(@sql) - 11);

SET @final_sql = 
'SELECT CONCAT(`tab_name`, ''-'',
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(`column_name`, '':'', sample ) ORDER BY ordinal_pos)) 
    AS result
 FROM ( <placeholder> ) AS sub
 GROUP BY tab_name';

SET @final_sql = REPLACE(@final_sql, '<placeholder>', @sql);

prepare s from @final_sql;
execute s;

deallocate prepare s;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4cb48/23/6)**</kbd>
<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo3`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df83b0/2/6)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔════════════════════════════╗
║           result           ║
╠════════════════════════════╣
║ tab0-id:1,col:a            ║
║ tab1-id:10,col2:2          ║
║ tab2-id:20,col3:2016-01-26 ║
╚════════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: I think they want the data from the column in there as well as the metadata. What you've got there looks like the first half of their question which is already working.