# How do i get all table names who match a specific regex in mysql 8.0?

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm trying to retrieve all tables with specific name format,
for performing union among those tables. 
I'm using **mysql  Ver 8.0.13**, and i wrote this following query for retrieving the relevant tables:

```
show tables LIKE REGEX '^table_.+_class$';
```

I couldn't figure out the correct syntax for this query :/

Afterwards i'm planning to **union all those tables**.

I would like to **avoid** writing this code since it doesn't scale  nicely:

```
SELECT * FROM table_french_class
UNION
SELECT * FROM table_history_class
UNION
SELECT * FROM table_pingpong_class
UNION
SELECT * FROM table_math_class
UNION
SELECT * FROM table_literature_class
```

Can someone suggest me how to handle this issue?

Thank you

Comment: It looks like all the tables should probably be just one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` catalog:

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME REGEXP '^table_.+_class$';
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `WHERE TABLE_NAME REGEXP '^table_.+_class$'`?

Comment: @LukaszSzozda  Great thank you, works like a charm!

Can you elaborate how can I now union all those tables name together?

Comment: @JammingThebBits If you want to do it dynamically you have to use prepared statement.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda Can you give me a tiny example?  thank you!

Comment: @JammingThebBits Sure https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35007416/retrieve-all-table-names-column-names-and-column-values-from-specifc-database/35007559#35007559